# Trying to add bookmark to pdf using PyPDF2

Tags: python, bookmarks, pypdf

I was trying to append a bookmark that holds the name and page number, but I cannot made it to save the file with the bookmark.
this is the code :

```
import PyPDF2 as pdf
import os

pth = r'D:\Haymovich\pythonScriptTry\pdf\old'
save_pth = r'D:\Haymovich\pythonScriptTry\pdf\new\MainPDF.pdf'


def pdf_marge(inp):
    mar = pdf.PdfFileMerger()
    for num, eachPDF in enumerate(os.listdir(inp)):
        eachPDF2 = os.path.join(pth, eachPDF)
        eachPDF3 = eachPDF.replace('.pdf', '')
        bookMark = mar.addBookmark(title=eachPDF3, pagenum=num)
        mar.append(fileobj=eachPDF2, bookmark=bookMark)
    return mar.write(save_pth)

print(pdf_marge(pth))
```

and this is the bookmark:

{'/Title': 'NESS01-2020', '/Page': 0, '/Type': '/FitH', '/Top': 826}

{'/Title': 'NESS01-2021', '/Page': 1, '/Type': '/FitH', '/Top': 826}

{'/Title': 'NESS02-2020', '/Page': 2, '/Type': '/FitH', '/Top': 826}

{'/Title': 'NESS03-2020', '/Page': 3, '/Type': '/FitH', '/Top': 826}

can anyone help me to save the pdf with the bookmark please?

Answer (score 0):

You are not opening the file

Change

```
return mar.write(save_pth)
```

To

```
with open(save_pth, "wb") as new_pdf:
    mar.write(new_pdf)
```

Comment: Nope, sorry, it does the same thing, I try to add the bookmark to the start of the file :(